# Why need to store next item pointer in linked list

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

This question popped in my mind when I was working on certain linked list data structure in my simple virtual machine, so why we need to store a pointer to the next element in the data structure itself, like this:

```
struct Name
    {
       int element1;
       float element2;
       void *nextItem;
    };
```

why not instead of that store the pointer to next item in array so we can access any node directly? and we can make a linked list of arrays in to ensure that we have similar flexibility of adding new items to the list, such as:

```
struct Name
    {
      int element1;
      float element2;
    };

struct arrayOfpointers
 {
   void *Items[FIXED_SIZE];
   void *nextArray;
 };
```

where arrayOfpointers->Items[1] is pointer to the second elemnt of Name data strucure? Isn't this technique much faster to reach specific item of linked list than ordinary one?

Comment: No, because you still have to traverse the array and now you've added extra memory (for the array and contents) plus code. Why would you think it would be faster to traverse the array contents than the linked list? Plus what happens when you need to insert or delete an element? You have to rearrange the entire array, while with the linked list you just do it directly.

Comment: @KenWhite if FIXED_SIZE constant set properly, the memory overhead will be negligible

Comment: It's going to be FIXED_SIZE * sizeof(pointer), plus code to iterate, plus extra memory allocation for any insertions, plus code to mark the last item in the array (if it's FIXED_SIZE but you don't use all or remove one, you have to track the last index used). It's a waste of code and effort and overhead for zero gain.

Comment: Yes, but I'm already storing pointer in the nodes in traditional way, so the only overhead is in any additional array items allocated without using them + pointer of next array, so if we set small or medium value for FIXED_SIZE the memory overhead will be small or even negligible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> why not store the pointer to next item in array so we can access any node directly?

Because this would convert your linked list data structure into an array.

Essentially, this would make your data structure behave in several different ways:

- Insertion in the middle would be O(n) instead of O(1)
- Deletion would be O(n) instead of O(1)
- Insertions would require reallocation and copy of the "tail"
- Deletion would require a copy of the "tail"

If it is OK for your system to have a data structure with O(n) inserts and deletes, you could use an array instead:

```
struct Name {
    int element1;
    float element2;
} nameArray[FIXED_SIZE];
```

There would be no need for the `next` link, because the data would be located in memory sequentially

Comment: You're right, however in some cases (such as my case) this technique provide fast random access (I use this list to store _large to medium_ pages of dynamically allocated memory) and having linked lists of arrays can help reducing the work needed to delete item, so we only need to change one array in the linked list of arrays

Comment: @ParcRoi If you need a combination of fast access and fast allocation, consider [skip lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) which let you access data very quickly (though not exactly giving you a random access).

Comment: Nice technique, maybe i will try implementing my technique and test how it work if it didn't work I may try your suggested technique (it look very elegant). Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Might be faster for random accesses but you have to take into account that each operation on the list has to be reflected on the adress array ,and each IO has to pass through it.Kind of a maintenance hell.

And of you want to do something like that you can always make an array of node pointers